# Dynamically create one table row or TextView for each SharedPreference?

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, android-relativelayout, tablerow

I have next xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context="info.senyk.ustat3.StatActivity"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextLogin"
    android:background="#ffff2341"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">


</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Login"
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:onClick="onClickButtonLogin" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextLogin"
    android:ems="4"
    android:hint="@string/Login"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scrollView"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextAt"
    android:hint="\@"
    android:editable="false"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextHostname"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editTextHostname" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextHostname"
    android:hint="@string/Hostname"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextColon"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editTextColon"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextColon"
    android:hint="@string/Colon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextPort"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editTextPort"
    android:inputType="none" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextPort"
    android:text="@string/Port22"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:ems="4"
    android:hint="@string/Password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextColon0"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextAt"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editTextAt"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextColon0"
    android:hint="@string/Colon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextLogin"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextLogin"
    android:inputType="none" />
```

I have three `editText` for Login, Password and Hostname and button Login

In top of the screen I have `ScrollView` and I need save credentials. But I want save all distinct hostname (like a history) every time when user press button login.

I mean it need to dynamic create one table row or `TextView` for each credential?

Any ideas?

Comment: What about [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Isnt a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) better for that? It can be customized for having more than a line of text.

For your current layout I would use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) instead of a scrollView, you can add elements programmatically to that by adding them to the ArrayList you use for keeping track of the history then calling

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

By the way you can even save said ArrayList to SharedPreferences as you wanted or a database by making it into a String (and back) since ArrayList implements Serializable

Comment: I want same like Connect bot (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=uk) on 3 picture

Comment: Okay then use a ListView as I described, one with a custom [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) to customize the looks of the entries in case you want to do so (like in that app with the green dot etc)